# Why Typescript doesn't get that at least one variable won't be null?

Tags: typescript

Given a type `SomeType`, I have two variables that can be `null` or of that type. This way:

```
let a: SomeType|null;
let b: SomeType|null;
```

Then, if I assign values to both variables (which can be an instance of `SomeType` or `null`) and validate them using the following logic, `c` is still of type `SomeType|null`.

```
if (!a && !b) {
  return;
}

const c = a || b;
```

However, it's sure that `c` is not `null`, because of the condition before the assignment.

Casting the variable to the type works, but it looks a bit hacky:

```
const c = (a || b) as SomeType;
```

Why TS doesn't get that without the cast? There is a way to make it more obvious for the compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only individual variables can be narrowed. The sort of dependent relationship between the types of different variables you're looking for isn't something the compiler can do. But in this case, an easy tweak to make things readable without an ugly `as` is to assign to `c` in advance, and then check *it* and return if needed:

```
const c = a || b;
if (!c) {
  return;
}
// now c will be inferred to be SomeType
```